# How do I map across a nested array of objects?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, graphql, sanity

So my issue is this, I'm using Sanity.io to manage content in an illustrator's portfolio page.

I'm trying to access an image gallery I've put into every project the illustrator has done.

My data is nested like this:

[data structure I'm trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCxBz.png)

I'm trying to access it like this:

```
{data.sanityProject.gallery.images.map((image) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={image.id}>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={image.asset.gatsbyImageData}
                // alt={image.image.title}
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
...
```

The resulting error message is this:

```
Cannot read property 'gatsbyImageData' of undefined
<SwiperSlide key={image.id}>
  138 |               <GatsbyImage
> 139 |                 image={image.asset.gatsbyImageData}
      |                                   ^
  140 |                 // alt={image.title}
  141 |               />
  142 |             </SwiperSlide>
```

I know this approach is close, but wrong. I'm not sure how to tackle this. I'm still new a developer and I'm more than aware that this is probably something very simple I'm missing but I just don't know where to look for answers.

Any help would be hugely appreciated and also received as a learning experience.

Take care everybody.

Answer (score 0):

`images` is an array of objects of this shape:

```
{
   image: {
      id: ...,
      asset: ...,
      // etc.
   }
}
```

So in order to access them correctly you should change your code slightly:

```
{data.sanityProject.gallery.images.map((imageItem) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={imageItem.image.id}>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={imageItem.image.asset.gatsbyImageData}
                // alt={image.image.title}
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
```

You could go for a more succinct (yet advanced) syntax ([Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)):

```
{data.sanityProject.gallery.images.map(({image}) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={image.id}>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={image.asset.gatsbyImageData}
                // alt={image.image.title}
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
```

Comment: This was the one, thank you so much!

I realise my problem now was worrying too much that the object names were 0,1,2,3...

...and that it doesn't really matter what the .map iterator is called.

Thank you again and have a great day!

Stay safe

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept the best answer if it solved your issue